# How to access SharePoint webDav on it own server

Tags: sharepoint-server, webdav

I have a problem when connecting to SharePoint WebDav on it own SharePoint server by public URL, It displayed authentication popup repeatedly, even authentication was successfully.

```
\\\test.echilli.cv\DavWWWRoot\HCB\Filing\8000844
```

But I can access the URL from my local machine.

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the loopback check problem. The methods for resolving this are described at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861 (the symptoms described here are slightly different to your issue, but I believe the cause is the same, and he same methods would resolve it).

Method 2 is generally good for a Dev or Test server, but for Production you should consider Method 1 (unless you understand and accept the security implications of Method 2).

Answer (score -1):

Try this link. You can also use SharePoint Explorer.

http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-site-using-webdav-sharepoint-2013

SA

Comment: The question indicates that user47705 does know how use WebDav, but is experiencing an issue when they do.